# how to close and restart a Python websocket thread?

Tags: python, websocket, python-multithreading

I'm trying to close and restart a websocket thread but can't, code below:

```
import threading
import websocket


pair = 'XRPMYR'

# Create a restart flag
to_restart_wsl[pair] = False

def wsl_thread(pair):
    wsl_url = f"wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/{pair}"
    while not to_restart_wsl[pair]:
        try:
            wsl = websocket.WebSocketApp(wsl_url, on_open=lambda ws: wsl_open(ws, pair), on_message=lambda ws, msg: wsl_message(ws, msg, pair))
            print(f"{pair} Luno websocket feed started.")
            wsl.run_forever()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        time.sleep(5)


# Create and start the thread
luno_thread = threading.Thread(target=wsl_thread, args=(pair,), name=pair)
luno_thread.start()

# Stop the thread
to_restart_wsl[pair] = True
luno_thread.join()

# Restart the thread
to_restart_wsl[pair] = False
luno_thread = threading.Thread(target=wsl_thread, args=(pair,))
luno_thread.start()
```

I suspect it's because inside `wsl_thread()`, `wsl.run_forever()` is running forever and doesn't complete the loop to check for `to_restart_wsl[pair]`, so it never gets stopped. How can I actually stop the websocket thread to restart it?

I tried looking for ways to kill the thread inside threading module, but there's no way to do it and the only way is `Thread.join()` which will wait for the thread to complete, but the thread never completes since `run_forever()` is running forever.

edit:
I tried creating a separate thread that uses `.close()` to try to close the same websocket connection, hoping it will close and `wsl_thread()` will exit, and then restart it. Code below, will check and try later to see if it works.

edit4:
the below code doesn't work, it doesn't close the same websocket connection but instead opens a new instance and closes that, i've figured out the solution in answer below

```
def close_wsl(pair):
    wsl_url = f"wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/{pair}"
    try:
        wsl = websocket.WebSocketApp(wsl_url)
        wsl.close()
        error_log(f"{pair} websocket feed closed, it should auto restart.")
    except Exception as e:
        error_log(e)

to_restart_wsl[pair] = True
close_wsl(pair)
luno_thread.join()

to_restart_wsl[pair] = False
luno_thread = threading.Thread(target=wsl_thread, args=(pair,))
luno_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to figure out the solution, add the `to_restart_wsl[pair]` flag inside the `wsl_message` function, when the flag is turned True it will run the `.close()` method and will then close the wsl connection, thereafter `.run_forever()` inside `wsl_thread` will reconnect again

```
import threading
import websocket


pair = 'ETHMYR'

# create a restart flag
to_restart_wsl[pair] = False

def wsl_thread(pair):
    wsl_url = f"wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/{pair}"
    while True:
        try:
            wsl = websocket.WebSocketApp(wsl_url, on_open=lambda wsl: wsl_open(wsl, pair), on_message=lambda wsl, msg: wsl_message(wsl, msg, pair))
            print(f"{pair} Luno websocket feed started.")
            wsl.run_forever()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        time.sleep(3)

def wsl_message(wsl, msg, pair):
    # do something with msg
    if to_restart_wsl[pair]:
        wsl.close()
        to_restart_wsl[pair] = False

# create and start the thread
luno_thread = threading.Thread(target=wsl_thread, args=(pair,), name=pair)
luno_thread.start()

# restart the thread
to_restart_wsl[pair] = True
```